# Insert without refresh in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii

i am developing a web application using yii2 .i did a thumbs up and thumbs down buttons. it just insert the user and what the person choose up /down into a table . but i don't think i am going about it the right way because after the user clicks up or down it refreshes. i want it to insert without refreshing.

this is the view

```
       <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => "contact-form",
            'enableClientValidation' => false,
            ]); 
          ?>
     <input type="hidden"  class="form-control"  value="up" required="true" name="Thumbs[rate]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
     <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>   
     <button type="submit" id="save" name="save">enter</button>  
     <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>   

                 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => "contact-form",
        'enableClientValidation' => false,
        ]); 
      ?>
 <input  type="hidden" class="form-control" hidden="true" value="down" required="true" name="Thumbs[rate]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
 <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?> 
     <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

if you notice i seem to have kept the value of up and down in a input with type hidden. just want to know of a better way to do it.

this is my controller function

```
 public function actionBlog()
    { 
     $thumbs= new Thumbs(); 
       $thumbs->user=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
          $thumbs->topic_id = '1';

        if ($thumbs->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $thumbs->validate()) {
        $thumbs->load($_POST);

         $thumbs->save();
          return $this->refresh();
     }

         return $this->render('blog');

    }
```

i also tried to used ajax but it seems not to be working well

Comment: Using hidden inputs is fine.  The refresh will happen by default when you submit the form.  You could use jQuery to 1) prevent the submit, then 2) use ajax to submit the data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pjax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html) for this.

Here is a simple **example** that you should be able to apply to your problem. I have included some comments for clarity, but I would heavily advise checking out [this tutorial](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/) for further information and some extended examples.

View (vote.php):

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use common\models\Thumbs;
?>

<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
<?= Html::a('', ['site/upvote'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up']) ?>
<?= Html::a('', ['site/downvote'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down']) ?>
<h1><?= Thumbs::find()->where(['=', 'post_id', '1'])->one()->votes ?></h1>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

SiteController:

```
public function actionVote()
{
    return $this->render('vote');
}

public function actionUpvote()
{
    // find the thumbs record for the related post
    $thumbsRecord = Thumbs::find()->where(['=', 'post_id', '1'])->one();

    // increment the thumbs count
    $thumbsRecord->votes += 1;

    // ensure change persists to db
    $thumbsRecord->save();

    // return value to the view
    return $this->render('vote', [
        'votes' => $thumbsRecord->votes,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Similar functionality to actionUpvote
 */
public function actionDownvote()
{
    $thumbsRecord = Thumbs::find()->where(['=', 'post_id', '1'])->one();
    $thumbsRecord->votes -= 1;
    $thumbsRecord->save();
    return $this->render('vote', [
        'votes' => $thumbsRecord->votes,
    ]);
}
```

The model is just a table that contains the following fields:

- id (int, primary key)
- post_id (int)
- votes (int, default 0)

Comment: Still the same thing I just don't want it to refresh after it insert

Comment: Have you tried removing this line of code: return $this->refresh(); from your controller - actionBlog? You won't need to refresh the page to update the thumbs count if you're updating via Pjax.

Comment: I have tried this but it automatically inserts in the database just by rendering the page. Is there a request for pjax just like a post request in a activeForm to prevent my pjax from executing the action in my controller right after rendering the page?